# return and call several arrays

Tags: c#

I have got a method which returns five arrays of different dimensions:

```
public static (string[],string[],string[,],string[,],string[,]) deserializeobject(string filename)
{
    return (Auftraggeber, Aufstellungsort, Anlagen, Vorgang_rückgemeldet, Vorgang_zukünftig);
}
```

How do I correctly call this method to further work with the arrays?

Comment: `var bob = deserializeobject("filenamehere");`

Comment: And then `var ar1 = bob.Item1; var ar2 = bob.Item2`...

Comment: Note that you can even: `(string[],string[],string[,],string[,],string[,]) bob = deserializeobject("filenamehere");`

Comment: And you can even name your parameters like so `string[] Foo` so that you can do `bob.Foo`

Comment: I would return from  method List<List<string>> or even a Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: Just create a new class for this purpose. Even if its just for the readability.

Comment: As Caramiriel wrote, you need a special type of hate for your co-workers to return so many nameless items together :-)

Comment: I would stronly suggest to create a class for that, in particular as the method is public and thus could be used in multiple contexts. That makes it far easier for users of your API to determine the meaning of every returned member.

Comment: how about using wrapper class around all the string[]?

Comment: How about `public static deserializeobject(string filename, ref str1 string[],ref str2 string[],ref str3 string[,], ref str4 string[,], ref str5 string[,])` if you don't want to use a class (which might be the best way to go).

Comment: @erk Probaby `out` instead of `ref`.

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, that one probably works even better...!

Answer (score 3):

I would stronly suggest to create a class for that, in particular as the method is public and thus could be used in multiple contexts. That makes it far easier for users of your API to determine the meaning of every returned member.

Your individual members seem to have a descene tmeaning anyway, so why throw it away and return a collection of namesless paramaters?

```
class MyObject
{
    public string[] Auftraggeber { get; set; }
    public string[] Aufstellungsort { get; set; }
    public string[] Anlagen { get; set; }
    public string[] Vorgang_rückgemeldet { get; set; }
    public string[] Vorgang_zukünftig { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public static MyObject Deserialize(string fileName)
{
    return new MyObject { AuftragGeber = ... };
}
```

Now users of your method can easily determine what the parameters mean:

```
var o = deserialize(myFile);
DoSomething(o.Aufstellungsort);
```

which is far easier to read than this:

```
var o DoSomething(myFile);
DoSomething(o.Item2);
```

isn´t it? Apart from this it limits typos. In the second case users can easily type `Item2` when they actually ment `Item1`, which may cause headache when debugging. With a descent name for every member those typos are far more unlikely.

Comment: Just my opinion: Although UTF-8 is supported I would suggest against using Umlaute as variable names, just imagine one colleague uses an English keyboard layout and a variable name starts with an Umlaut; you can esentially bin intellisense for that. It's fine in comments though...

Comment: @Freggar Thanks for pointing that out. But as it doesn´t belong to my answer and is in the question also, I won´t put that into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First the response to your question:

Given:

```
public static (string[], string[], string[,], string[,], string[,]) deserializeobject(string filename)
{
    // Some value that will be returned... Just doing a test here
    return default((string[], string[], string[,], string[,], string[,]));
}
```

You can:

```
// Using var
var des1 = deserializeobject("foo.bin");
Console.WriteLine($"Lengths: {des1.Item1.Length}, {des1.Item2.Length}, {des1.Item3.Length}, {des1.Item4.Length}, {des1.Item5.Length}");

// Legal, but too much verbose
(string[], string[], string[,], string[,], string[,]) des2 = deserializeobject("foo.bin");

// Legal too, because in truth the ValueTuple<> struct is used
ValueTuple<string[], string[], string[,], string[,], string[,]> des3 = deserializeobject("foo.bin");
```

Now, the problem here is that, as I've written in a comment, you need a special type of hate for your coworkers to do this. Why? Because if I ask you, what is `Item4`, can you give me a response? No :-) Fortunately there are two alternatives: creating a full class/struct to contain the return value or using named tuples. I'm quite against creating a class that will be used only by a single method, so I'll show you the named tuples way.

Using named tuples you can:

```
public static (string[] Auftraggeber, string[] Aufstellungsort, string[,] Anlagen, string[,] VorgangRückgemeldet, string[,] VorgangZukünftig) deserializeobject2(string filename)
{
    return default((string[], string[], string[,], string[,], string[,]));
}
```

Then you can:

```
// Using var, with named arguments:
var des4 = deserializeobject2("foo.bin");
Console.WriteLine($"Lengths: {des4.Auftraggeber.Length}, {des4.Aufstellungsort.Length}, {des4.Anlagen.Length}, {des4.VorgangRückgemeldet.Length}, {des4.VorgangZukünftig.Length}");
```

See? The name of the items (arrays) returned by your method is maintained...

Note that named tuples are a sleight of hand. There are no named tuples underside. There are only `ValueTuple<>` that are "annotated" with the name of the properties that you want.

This is legal:

```
ValueTuple<string[], string[], string[,], string[,], string[,]> des5 = des4;
```

Full example to the question in comment:

```
public static (string[] Auftraggeber, string[] Aufstellungsort, string[,] Anlagen, string[,] VorgangRückgemeldet, string[,] VorgangZukünftig) deserializeobject2(string filename)
{
    // Define/create/fill the arrays
    var auftraggeber = new string[10];
    var aufstellungsort = new string[10];
    var anlagen = new string[10, 10];
    var vorgangRückgemeldet = new string[10, 10];
    var vorgangZukünftig = new string[10, 10];

    // Return the arrays
    return (auftraggeber, aufstellungsort, anlagen, vorgangRückgemeldet, vorgangZukünftig);
}
```

Comment: To complete the options, theres deconstructing too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct - the concept is rather new though.

Comment: @Caramiriel Deconstructing alone doesn't solve the problem that by looking at the signature of the method you can't know what are the "values" of the various returned items. You must still use named tuples, and then you can deconstruct if you prefer.

Comment: I don't see really an advantage over a class. You could easily extend a class but adding fields to the tulpe esentially changes the method signature and could potentially cause bad things to happen.

Comment: @Freggar In this particular case, where the method is called `deserialize` and probably deserializes a "business" object then using a full fledged class is probably a good idea. This "business" object has a standing in the program and is probably central to some parts of it. It can be reused by various methods. But if the returned object is only a carrier that will disappear 5 lines below the call to `deserialize` then I consider it only to be a pain. But as always YMMV.

Comment: @xanatos thanks! Do I have to define the arrays again inside the method? Because whein I do not, the names dous not exist in the context

Comment: If it would disappear five lines indicating it´s used only in a very special case it´s hardly part of the public API, isn´t it?

Comment: @AnneMartin Unclear what you are asking... Written an example at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use Tuple<> like below code :

```
   public Tuple<int[], int[]> GetMultipleValue(string name)
   {
      int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4}
      int[] b = new int[]{5,6,7,8}
      return Tuple.Create(a,b);
   }
```